# Displaying text in table PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I would like to create a table with 3 columns one for the name of the value for example "Number of Follower", a second column for the `$tweetstimeline` values described in the code, and a third column for the '$tweetstimeline_2' values.

I have tried using `<tr>`, `<td`> and `<th>` however I am still new to this and did not get the correct results. Could anyone provide a solution please?

```
echo "Number of Followers: ".$tweetstimeline[0]->user->followers_count;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Name of Twitter Page: ".$tweetstimeline[0]->user->name;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Location: ".$tweetstimeline[0]->user->location;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Description: ".$tweetstimeline[0]->user->description;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "URL: ".$tweetstimeline[0]->user->url;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Number of Friends: ".$tweetstimeline[0]->user->friends_count;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Number of Statuses: ".$tweetstimeline[0]->user->statuses_count;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "<br />\n";


echo "Number of Followers: ".$tweetstimeline_2[0]->user->followers_count;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Name of Twitter Page: ".$tweetstimeline_2[0]->user->name;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Location: ".$tweetstimeline_2[0]->user->location;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Description: ".$tweetstimeline_2[0]->user->description;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "URL: ".$tweetstimeline_2[0]->user->url;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Number of Friends: ".$tweetstimeline_2[0]->user->friends_count;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "Number of Statuses: ".$tweetstimeline_2[0]->user->statuses_count;
echo "<br />\n";
echo "<br />\n";
```

Comment: what's the outputed html ?

Comment: Were your `tr, td, th`s in a `table`?

Comment: Without `<tr>`, `<td>` and `<th>` elements we can speak about table in HTML. You have no table, just many lines of plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the table structure that you want it's incorrect. Try something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td># Tweetstimeline</td>
            <td>Number of followers</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Url</td>
            <td>Friends Count</td>
            <td>Status count</td>       
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $rows = 2; //number of rows goes here
            for($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; $i++){
                //output html row:
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>$i</td>";
                    echo "<td> $tweetstimeline[$i]->user->followers_count </td>";
                    echo "<td> $tweetstimeline[$i]->user->name </td>";
                    echo "<td> $tweetstimeline[$i]->user->location </td>";
                    echo "<td> $tweetstimeline[$i]->user->description </td>";
                    echo "<td> $tweetstimeline[$i]->user->url </td>";
                    echo "<td> $tweetstimeline[$i]->user->friends_count </td>";
                    echo "<td> $tweetstimeline[$i]->user->statuses_count </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }               
        ?>  
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

PS: Sorry for my English, I'm learning

Answer (score 1):

Try basic html table structure:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header 1</th>
            <th>header 2</th>
            <th>header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content 1</td>
            <td>content 2</td>
            <td>content 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After `<tbody>` You can use `foreach` to iterate over all elements.

```
foreach ($tweetstimeline as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row->user->name}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row->user->location}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row->user->description}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Number of Followers</td>";
echo "<td>$tweetstimeline</td>      ";
echo "<td>$tweetstimeline_2</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>100</td>";
echo "<td>wtfgoeshere?</td>";   
echo "<td>and here?</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>30</td>";
echo "<td>wtfgoeshere</td>  ";  
echo "<td>and here?</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>60</td>";
echo "<td>wtfgoeshere</td>  ";  
echo "<td>and here?</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Try something like this as a starting point and just do "code" + varhere + "endcode" as you feel fit.